# Chrome-extension : Display a picture in a popup with AJAX and JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm currently developing a chrome extension which permits to display a picture when the user sends a word. I use AJAX and JQUERY to get the picture.

I've a problem to **display the picture within the popup**. In fact, it works on a normal html page but not in the popup.

If you want to test : http://algec.iut-blagnac.fr/~groupe6pjt/testAjax/pageHTML.html.

When I try to display the picture in the popup, I've this error in the JavaScript console :

> Failed to load resource  chrome-extension://pmbnmemdpheopedlikgmdeegebojkoji/chamoix.png

And I've a little image icon with a crack on it instead of the picture.

I don't think it's a problem on the path of the picture cause it's work on our page (link above).

**Here's my code :**

**1. more_com.php (the php file on the server)**

```
<?php

    print "<p>Je suis un fichier php 2.0 !</p>";

        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "groupe6pjt", "bfjrs2012") or die ("Connexion impossible");
        $base="groupe6pjt";
        mysql_select_db("$base") or die ("base inconnue"); 

        $requete2 = "select imgSigne from signe where idSigne=10;";
        $resultat2 = mysql_query($requete2) or die ("requete2 impossible");
        while($tab = mysql_fetch_array($resultat2))
        {
            echo $tab[0];
            echo "<br/><img  src=\"chamoix.png\" />";
        }
?>
```

**2. popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<title>Techniques AJAX - XMLHttpRequest</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="bandeau">
<h4 style="color : white;">AIPS - Traduction LSF</h4>
</div>

<div id="obtenirTexte" class="well well-large">
<p><b>1)</b> Obtenir le texte surligné sur la page : </p>
    <form class="form-search">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input class="span2 search-query" name="text" style="height : 30px; width : 175px;" type="text" id="text"/><button id="effacer" class="btn btn-primary" name="effacer" style="height : 30px;" title="Effacer le mot"><img src="effacer.png" alt="Erreur"/></button>
    </div><br/><br/>
        <button id="submit" class="btn" title="1) Texte">Obtenir le texte</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="obtenirImage" class="well well-large">

    <div id="commentaires">
    <p><b>2)</b> Obtenir l'image correspondante : </p>
    </div>

    <form>
        <input id="more_com" class="btn" type="button" value="Obtenir l'image" title="2) Image"/>
    </form>

    <div id="message">
        <!-- PHP return here ! -->
    </div>

</div>
<!-- As you can see with Chrome you can't put script directly in the htlm code so I create a file with my function : fonction.js -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="fonction.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="fonction2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**3. fonction.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#more_com").click(function(){                                                                      //Cette fonction se déclenche quand on clique sur le bouton d'id "more_com" (ici "Obtenir l'image")
            var variableTest=$.ajax({
                 url : "http://algec.iut-blagnac.fr/~groupe6pjt/testAjax/more_com.php",      //Ca c'est la page PHP qu'on va devoir modifier pour qu'à la reception du mot elle affiche l'image correspondante (Ne pas changer !)
                 type : "GET",                                                                                                                                                                                           //On garde GET car on veut récupérer une donnée en envoyant des infos ( != POST )
                 //data : 'motRecher=' + COUCOU;      // *****A MODIFIER*****                  //On va devoir utiliser ce champ pour envoyer le mot surligné vers la page PHP "more_com.php" 
                 dataType : "html",                                                                                                                                                                              //Le type de données renvoyé par la page PHP (ici : c'est du html que la page renvoie)
            });

            variableTest.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                             //Si on atteind le fichier alors on affiche ce que retourne "more_com.php" (ici il retourne "Je suis un fichier PHP !")
              $("#message").html(data);                                                                                                                                     //Permet l'affichage du fichier PHP
            });

            variableTest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){                                            //Si on atteind pas le fichier ...
                $("#message").html("<p>Erreur</p>");                                                   //...erreur
            });
        });
    });
```

I think Chrome prevents the display of the picture in the popup or something like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the image is defined as such

```
<img src="./chamoix.png">
```

This relative path resolves to

```
http://algec.iut-blagnac.fr/~groupe6pjt/testAjax/chamoix.png
```

on the web page but tries to resolve to

```
chrome-extension://pmbnmemdpheopedlikgmdeegebojkoji/chamoix.png
```

in the extension. Try using an absolute path or a `replace()` to point it to the correct address.